# Looking for a DM tool Similar to Masterplan For 5E

Tags: dnd-5e, tool-recommendation

I'm looking for a DM tool like Masterplan for 5e (standalone tool, offline preferred) for making loot tables, plot and quest tracking. Or maybe is there an Add-on to the original Masterplan for other editions?

Comment: Apparently [WotC has forbidden HeroLab](http://community.wizards.com/forum/dd-next-general-discussion/threads/3944656) to use the license for 5e, so we won't see support there either.

Comment: (Kind of) Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/tree-based-tool-to-create-dialog/34817#34817

Answer (score 5):

The official Wizards-affiliated 5E digital tools were called [Codename: Morningstar](http://www.codenamemorningstar.com/) while in beta, then [re-named Dungeonscape and later disassociated with Wizards of the Coast](http://www.trapdoortechnologies.com/dungeonscape/), but they will apparently continue in some less-affiliated form.

Comment: This is awesome to note. Thanks for the information. I missed it somehow.

Comment: Sadly, discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise you to wait and stick to traditional planning for now. Tho Masterplan is an excellent tool for mapping out your campaign and registering plot-related data, you have to take into account that 5th Edition isn't officially out yet, and it's nearly impossible to develop a software for it on its current state, since we don't even have Monster Data outside of Playtest and Starter Set.

I'm impatient too, but I bet you can make do with Masterplan for now. Only 20 days left for the release of Full Basic PDF, and even then don't expect someone to pull off a DMing software for the time being, give it time.

Comment: yeah i know, i was wondering if i can atleast change some values but well i think i should wait :(

Answer (score -1):

TreeDBNotes is a great freeware alt. to any purchase for Data Structuring and self contained notebooks. There is a Pro version as well that rivals OneNote.